# android reading from 2 different files

Tags: java, android, file-io

in my android app im trying to set 2 text views names from 2 different files but for some reason the first text view is being set as the 2nd files information "ingredient 2 " and the 2nd text view isnt being displayed at all? am i doing something wrong with the way im setting and opening my files?

```
public class GroceriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView groceryname1, groceryname2, groceryname3, groceryname4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_groceries);


        groceryname1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grocery1);
        groceryname2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grocery2);
        groceryname3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grocery3);
        groceryname4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grocery4);

        String message;
        String message2;
        FileInputStream fis1 = null;
        FileInputStream fis2 = null;
        FileInputStream fis3 = null;
        FileInputStream fis4 = null;
        try {
            fis1 = openFileInput("Ingredient1");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis1);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            while ((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(message);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        groceryname1.setText(sb.toString());
        try {
            fis1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            fis2 = openFileInput("Ingredient2");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputStreamReader isr2 = new InputStreamReader(fis2);
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(isr2);
        StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            while ((message2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                sb2.append(message2);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        groceryname2.setText(sb2.toString());
        try {
            fis2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

so as tldr im trying to set textview1 as ingredient1 and textview2 as ingredient2 but right now textview1 is being set as ingredient2 and textview2 is not being changed

EDIT: after fixing that error im now having the textview1 and textview2 being set as the first ingredient

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the result ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f02d93c5e6db3c5d4b044d2514f99d90

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
sb.append(message2);
```

to

```
sb2.append(message2);
```

Comment: after i changed that its putting the text from ingredient 1 in both textview 1 and textviww 2

Comment: are you sure that both ingredients are not the same?